# MVC 4 - Migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, migration, entity-framework-migrations

I am working in a project with some others programmers using MVC 4. We are in the beginning of the project, the first Sprint actually, and we have a lot of migrations in our migrations folder. I'd like to know if it's possible to reduce the number of migrations.

We have the possibility of creating only one single migration, but we want to know the historic , so we want to keep all of them. I just want to know if it's possible to divide them  inside some folders in order of having less files in the migration folder. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to reduce the number of migrations, which I've done in my project. If you've reached a good stopping point (and if the team agrees), you could delete all migrations (.cs Migration files and __MigrationHistory db entries). Then, enable Migrations again using the current version of the database, so you'll have a brand new (but hefty) InitialCreate.

From there on forward, you'll have a smaller number of migrations than you had yesterday, and the first file will represent everything that you have today.

Will that work for you and your team?

Comment: I was wondering something like division in folder, but I think this is not possible. Then, I'll talk to the team about this solution. Thanks btw.